# iOS and OSX build in one Xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I had a question regarding IOS projects and OSX projects on Xcode. Essentially I have a section of code that works under OSX base sdk (its mainly a OSIRIX plug in) and will only work by having an OSX base SDK. The OSX base sdk code just lets me choose images, I also have a section of code that will allow me to process the data from the images, this functions only under an iOS base SDK. Is there way to have two sections of code that function under different base sdk functioning under one .m file?

Please let me know if I am too vague, I am currently very confused on what to do about it.

Comment: So you have 2 targets in your Xcode project; one targeting iOS and the other OSX?

Comment: TARGET_OS_MAC and TARGET_OS_IPHONE ? or you want to build single  framework for 2 platforms?

Comment: I'm still a beginner, so I'm not entirely sure how to have the 2 targets each targeting a specific code and have it both code work under one .m file. I know that you can have an IOS target but I am not quite sure what to do with it.

Comment: Oh I got you, you want make work code which is linked to 2 different sdks(iOS and OS X) at the same time, do you? it's not possible

Comment: SakrisT, The main goal is to have an Ios application that processes images, the mac os code simply will take tools from an Mac osx application and allow me to sort through images, so I guess I want to be able to have the mac os code work under the application, but I get errors because they each work under different base SDK's

Comment: Its not possible? Oh I guess I will have try something else